# No error message during Spring Boot launch for nested @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my spring boot application, I have a class to deal with application.properties files

```
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cassandre.trading.bot.exchange")
public class ExchangeParameters
```

This class has properties like this:

```
/** Exchange name. For example : coinbase, kraken, kucoin. */
@NotEmpty(message = "Exchange name required, for example : coinbase, kraken, kucoin...")
private String name;

/** API username. */
@NotEmpty(message = "API username required")
private String username;
```

If spring boot don't find them, I have correct error messages like :

```
Property: cassandre.trading.bot.exchange.secret
Value: null
Reason: API secret required

Property: cassandre.trading.bot.exchange.name
Value: null
Reason: Exchange name required, for example : coinbase, kraken, kucoin...
```

But in my class, I also have nested properties:

```
/** Modes. */
@Valid
private static Modes modes = new Modes();

/** API Calls rates. */
@Valid
private static Rates rates = new Rates();

/** Exchange API rate calls. */
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cassandre.trading.bot.exchange.modes")
public static class Modes {

        /** Set it to true to use the sandbox. */
        @NotNull(message = "Sandbox parameter required, set it to true to use the sandbox")
        private Boolean sandbox;

        /** Set it to true to use the dry mode. */
        @NotNull(message = "Dry parameter required, set it to true to use the dry mode")
        private Boolean dry;
```

If rates are missing, I have correct messages for the rates.

But I set no parameters at all, i have error messages for all fields except for nested properties like rates.

Any idea ? thanks a lot

Comment: Since you are initializing new Rates(), spring has no clue about it, since you are doing dependency inject not spring. It can be a simple inner class, use @Autowire on variables, if static is not absolutely needed.

Comment: new Rates set the field to null and as I have @NotNull, they should be on error no ?

Comment: I found the solution. Don't use static field and class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Don't use static field and class

Comment: yeah.. tht what I meant in my comment, _use @Autowire on variables, if static is not absolutely needed_